# Passing an Action, Func or delegate to a public method or constructor is a security issue

Tags: c#, .net, security, delegates

I heard that passing an action, function or delegate to a public method is a security issue.

I want to understand why or how this can be exploited because I cannot find a way to do it.

At least.. is it a best practice to not pass delegates to classes?

Examples of so called vulnerable code:

- Public constructor action:

```
public class MyClass { public MyClass(Action doSomething) { doSomething?.Invoke(); } }
```

with the calling code in another project using my code as a reference:

```
var securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl = new Action(() => { ... });
var instance = new MyClass(securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl);
```

- Public constructor action with parameter:

```
public class MyClass
{
public MyClass(Action<string> doSomething)
{
doSomething?.Invoke("something");
}
}
```

with the calling code in another project using my code as a reference:

```
var securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl = new Action<string>((someParameter) => { ... });
var instance = new MyClass(securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl);
```

- Same so called issue can happen with functions or delegates passed to public constructor.
- Public method with action:

```
public class MyClass { public void MyAction(Action doSomething) { doSomething?.Invoke(); } }
```

with the calling code in another project using my code as a reference:

```
var securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl = new Action(() => { ... });
var instance = new MyClass();
instance.MyAction(securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl);
```

```
public class MyClass { public void MyAction(Action<string> doSomething) { doSomething?.Invoke("some string"); } }
```

with the calling code in another project using my code as a reference:

```
var securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl = new Action<string>((someParameter) => { ... });
var instance = new MyClass();
instance.MyAction(securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl);
```

- Same so called issue can happen with functions or delegates passed to public methods.

How is it different than the following code using events?

```
var securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl = new Action(() => { ... });
var instance = new MyClass();
instance.MyEvent += (s, e) => securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl;
```

Or how it is different from calling the method directly in a different project?

```
var securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl = new Action(() => { ... });
securityIssueActionOutsideOfMyControl?.Invoke();
```

Comment: Where did you hear this and what reasons were given?

Comment: Who told you that? It would apply to any type passed to a method where that type had public methods, since then the method to which it was passed could call those public methods - which is effectively no different than passing a delegate.

Comment: Two team leads both told me to avoid adding actions, functions or delegates to public methods or public constructors because it can be called with arbitrarily code (but in my opinion the "trusted application" is the only one who should be able to call it even if it's public, and if someone injected code even using an extension mechanism it's the extension mechanism issue not checking the called extensions (maybe without signing extensions), not the public method exposing a delegate being the real issue). Also private methods can be called using reflection.

Comment: Do they also tell you not to pass interfaces to methods? Because that also allows you to call methods with "arbitrary code". This advice sounds like a pile of poo to me.

Comment: They didn't tell me not to pass interfaces to methods. I agree that interfaces passed to methods, constructor and so on can hold many implemented actions that are executed the same way with "arbitrary code".